# Whenever i try to comeback from another screen my keyboard pop up everytime in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, flutter-layout

[image: application preview]

while cooming back from any screen to homescreen my keyboard pop-ups automatically which makes user experience bad.

Can someone tell me how to deal with this bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can run this code everywhere you change page:

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()
```

[github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48464)

Comment: Hey brother my issue got resolved in most of the pages but i am not getting how to apply it in a drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove what you set in textfield as autofocus true.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).